# MATLAB bsxfun with different non-singleton dimensions

Tags: matlab, histogram, vectorization, intersection, bsxfun

I have two (50 train and 25 test) sets of histograms of size 42. (These numbers are arbitrary, they will be much bigger in reality, so I'm looking for an efficient way. Also the convention might be reverse in terms of transposes, so feel free to use any convention [feature x observation] or [observation x feature] )

So `x1` is of size `[42, 50]` and `x2` is `[42, 25]`. I want to calculate the histogram intersection kernel of size `[50, 25]`. By a histogram intersection kernel I mean the sum of the vector that contains the minimum elements of two histograms. How can I do this with MATLAB?

I tried `k=sum(bsxfun(@min, x1,x2));` (with transpose variations) but I'm getting the error :

```
Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: so what should happen to elements contained in `x1` but not in `x2`. For example `x1(42,50) = 1984` and  `x2(42,50)` is not existing. Should this index be considered as **1984** or as **0**?

Comment: @thewaywewalk I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, however, that should be irrelevant. Because I want to encode how similar the 25 samples in `x2` are to the 50 samples in `x1`, hence a 50x25 kernel. In the train kernel, it will be 50x50 because `x2=x1`.

Comment: Alright, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an output of size `[50,25]` which is already summarized. The output of `bsxfun` should be of dimensions `[50,25,42]` which means all inputs must be of this size except for singleton dimensions. Your `[42, 50]` needs to be permute to `[50,1,42]` and the second input to `[1,25,42]`

```
x1=rand(42,50);
x2=rand(42,25);
x1=permute(x1,[2,3,1]);
x2=permute(x2,[3,2,1]);
t=bsxfun(@min, x1,x2);
k=sum(t,3);
```

Comment: Thanks ! But this code sample produces a `k` of size `1x25x42`.

Comment: @halilpazarlama: Forgot the `3` in the last line which tells `sum` to summarize among the third dimension.

Comment: Dear @Daniel, I have one more question. When I apply this code to my real test case, where feature dimension is 3700, and number of samples is 2700, my computer (with 12GB RAM) gives the error : `Error using bsxfun. Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.`. Are there any ways to make this further memory-efficient? **edit : ** I experimented and saw that the max. number of features I can use is around 400. So I think I'm asking for a miracle :) But maybe there is a way, like parallel programming, using the GPU etc.

Comment: I inserted an intermediate step to better explain the problem. Both your input matrixes x1 and x2 are of size [3700,2700] which is not a problem, that`s 76MiB, but the intermediate result which is returned by bsxfun is of size [3700,3700,2700] which would require 276GiB. Your final result is of size [3700,3700] so it should be possible to do this on a standard PC.

Comment: I don't find a good solution for the memory problem. As the original question is already answered and you accepted the answer, probably no one else will take a look at this. I recommend to create a new question.